# Using <Redirect> inside Routes stops Auth0 login from working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, auth0

I'm trying to set up auth0 for a single page react app that does not yet have authenticate. The app sometimes uses  and these seem to stop auth0 from working.

Below is a one page example of the root of my problem.

Replacing

```
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
        <Route path="/login"><LoginPage /></Route>
      </Switch>
```

with

```
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/"><LoginPage /></Route>
      </Switch>
```

allows login to work. I can't find any examples that use both Redirect and Auth0.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Auth0Provider, useAuth0} from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const LoginButton = () => {
    const {loginWithRedirect} = useAuth0();
    return <button onClick={loginWithRedirect}>Log In</button>
}

const LogoutButton = () => {
    const {logout} = useAuth0();
    return <button onClick={logout}>Log Out</button>
}

const LoginPage = () => {
    const {user, isLoading, isAuthenticated}    = useAuth0();

    if(isLoading) {
        return <h2>Loading</h2>;
    }

    if(!isAuthenticated) {
        return <div><h2>Not Authenticated</h2><LoginButton /></div>
    }
    return <div><h2>{user.name} is Authenticated.</h2><LogoutButton /></div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Auth0Provider>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
        <Route path="/login"><LoginPage /></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Auth0Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a separate callback route, checking the authentication there and then redirecting to the final url afterwards.

```
 <Router>
    <Auth0Provider ...credentials here...>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
        <Route path="/login"><LoginPage /></Route>
        <Route path="/auth0-callback"><CallbackPage /></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Auth0Provider>
  </Router>,
```